# What does "customer experience development" mean?

Tags: customer, customer-experience

In the description of one vacancy I read following:

> ...responsible for Internet and Mobile channels development, project
>   management, customer experience development.

What does **customer experience development** mean? I know what is [customer experience](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_experience), but I have a very vague idea of what from itself represents *customer experience development activity [during project management, of course]*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a generic PM problem or issue.

Comment: I disagree. By my opinion, Customer Experience Development (as part CX) is related with Project Management and should have some formal definition and description.

Comment: I would interpret this as "make the software easier to use."

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand how you can ask what the term means, but have a strong opinion that it is related to project management.  Let's resolve the ambiguity and re-open the question.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace It's easy. I know what CX mean. But I doesn't sure that I understand correctly meaning of "CX Development" term. Of course, CX management is not a part of Project management (it is separate discipline), but project management processes always include CX in themselves. Really, I can't imagine any project without "interaction between an organization and a customer". So, by my opinion, CX (or CXM, or CXD as a part of CXM) is related with PM. If you have other thoughts about this, please post them. Perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: @mkennedy Thank you for your comment. But I think that you mixed up UX (user experience) and CX (customer experience).

Comment: Ignore, posted comment to wrong item

Comment: If a term isn't standardized in your industry or sector, the only sensible thing to do is to ask the person who posted the job what it means *to them*. This is not a standard project management term, so it's probably off-topic for PMSE anyway. Even if it's related to some form of project management, trying to guess what someone else thinks it means for a particular role at a particular company is fundamentally a polling question, and is not suitable for this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's like continuous quality improvement. It is about **continuous improvement of the customer experience**. Or the person is responsible to manage / develop / improve/ increase the customer experience, e.g. over the project lifecycle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have very close thoughts about this. In the beginning I had two ideas: 1) CXD is just synonym for CXM. 2) CXD is a part of CXM and (as you wrote) this activity should improve interaction between an organization and a customer. Of course, I still have very vague idea about CDX, but I'm afraid, that to ask more details about CXD will be "too broad to PMSE" =)

Comment: Within CXM, you define a roadmap to develop CX composed of (e.g.) tasks and "quality gates". You'll have a strong coupling to the marketing department to get data and info regarding CX. And fore sure our activities will differ a lot if you look on a mass product or a single customer...

Answer (score 0):

Customer experience (CX) development also involves strategic decisions about 'what to improve' so that customers perceive their experience as excellent. For instance, if a CX manager is working for an omnichannel retailer such as Target, he/she needs to develop CX initiatives across [nine primary CX factors in omnichannel retailing](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jretai.2022.03.003). The primary CX factors would differ for different sectors, e.g., retails vs tourism vs education. Therefore, when thinking about CX development, the first task is to explore the primary CX factor in a specific context.